# Is the left derivative of this theta function zero at $1$?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, theta-functions

Is it true that
$$f(x):=\sum_{j=1}^\infty(-1)^j j^2 x^{j^2}\to0$$
as $x\uparrow1$?

(One may note that $f(x)=xh'(x)$, where $h(x):=\vartheta _4(0,x)/2$ and $\vartheta _4$ is a [theta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html), so that $f(1-)=h'(1-)$.)

---

Here is the graph $\{(x,f(x)):0.7<x<1\}$:

[image]

Comment: It seems correct, with very rapid convergence.  For $x=0.99$ the value is around $-10^{-101}$.

Comment: Yes, notice that the value is $-1 + 4 - 9 + 16 ... = -1 ( 1 - 4 + 9 - 16 ... ) = -1 *(0)$ per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%E2%88%92_2_%2B_3_%E2%88%92_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Generalization

Comment: What does the Jacobi identity give here?

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal : Thank you for your comment. In the Wikipedia article, they seem to have $0$ for the Abelian sum. Here it is a different, lacunary power series.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov : Thank you for your comment. Do you have a more specific suggestion, with a particular identity and a possible way to use it?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : Thank you for your comment. My numerics did suggest this question.

Comment: Well, Jacobi identities allows you to transform $x\to 1$ into $x\to 0$ I believe, and when $x\to 0$ the asymptotics of the derivative is easy to calculate, so maybe by doing the change of variables you get the asymptotics as $x\to 1$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis yes, the reason I mentioned it is that the boundary of lacunary series still often respect these questionable “identities”. See my comments at the answer of this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403882/divergent-series-summation-beyond-natural-boundaries/404203#comment1165512_404203 the regular Jacobi Theta function $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n^2}$, a lacunary function as well takes on the value $\frac{1}{2}$ at $x=-1$ and $1-1+1-1… = \frac{1}{2}$ which would be the unrigorous evaluation of the theta function at that point.

Comment: I'm confused. The title asks about the derivative, but the body just asks about the function.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : I have now explained this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing $x=e^{-a}$ for $a>0$ and then using the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) with $s(u)=e^{i\pi u} u^2 e^{-au^2}$ (in the notation of the Wikipedia article), we rewrite the sum in question as
$$G(a):=\frac12\,\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty g_a(k),$$
where
$$g_a(t):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty s(u)e^{-2\pi itu}\,du
=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }  \left(2 a-\pi
   ^2 (1-2 t)^2\right)}{4 a^{5/2}}\, 
e^{-\pi ^2 (1-2 t)^2/(4 a)}.$$
Letting now $a\downarrow0$ (which corresponds to $x\uparrow1$) and using dominated convergence, we get $G(0+)=0$. $\quad\Box$

---

It also follows that the convergence of $G(a)$ to $0$ as $a\downarrow0$ (or, equivalently, as $x\uparrow1$) is very fast, faster than that of any power of $a$ (or, equivalently, than that of any power of $1-x$). This corresponds to what we see in the picture in the OP.

Comment: Your method applies to geneal sums $\sum (-1)^j j^{2k} x^{j^{2r}}$, $k, r$ positive integers. One just needs that the Fourier transform of $x^{2k} e^{-a x^{2r}$ decays fast.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune : That's right. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Just a further remark, in case you are interested (I like both the problem and your solution). The method applies when $2k,2r$ (with the above notation) are just positive real numbers and the asymptotics depends only on $k$ and is zero iff $k$ is natural. One needs the asymptotics of the Fourier transform of $x^{2k} e^{-x^{2r}} \chi_{(0,\infty)}$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune : Thank you for this comment as well.